# How to change time scale with mouse drag in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, zooming, scale

IN SSRS2008:
I draw a chart that has time in x-axis.
I need my chart has ability that when i click on portion of chart or select portion of x-axis 
of chart by drag and drop my chart zoom to selected portion of time.
zoom in ssrs by default acts as picture zoom.but I need to zoom to specified portion of time.
anyone know how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS out of the box does not allow you to select a portion of a chart and zoom to greater detail. Your options are to either add a parameter to your report that allows the user to change the period of time to display on the x-axis or to add an action that allows the user to click on a data point in your chart and jump to another report with greater detail. This jump to report action could even jump to the same report but whether it's the same or different, you can pass in what the user clicked on as a parameter value that drives the level of detail in the new report. See this for more information on adding drillthrough to your report: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159847(v=sql.100).aspx.